# Why am I am getting "Cannot find name 'function name' error"?

Tags: javascript, typescript, arrow-functions

So I added this function below to my ts class:

```
 private get(iD: string): Promise <Function> => async () => {
        const tallConfig = await longCrudService.getHalf(iD);
        const stream: Stream = tallConfig.stream;
        const response = this.createUrl(tallConfig, stream);
        return response;
    }
```

But as soon as I add it, every other functions/Methods below it starts throwing this error: "Cannot find name 'function name'". Did I add it the wrong way?. I'm still trying to get a hold of typescript.

Comment: `: Promise <Function> => async () => {` should be `: Promise <Function> = async () => {`?

Answer (score 0):

```js
private get = async (id: string): Promise<Function> => {
```

or

```js
private get: (iD: string) => Promise<Function> = async (iD: string) => {
```

Comment: When I use any of these, I get error "type String is not assignable to type Function"

Comment: ```javascript
class A {
    private get1: (iD: string) => Promise<Function> = async (iD: string) => {
        return () => { return iD }
    }

    private get2 = async (id: string): Promise<Function> => {
        return () => { return id }
    }

    public test(iD: string) {
        this.get1(iD).then(v => v()).then(console.log)
        this.get2(iD).then(v => v()).then(console.log)
    }
}

const a = new A()

a.test("test")
```
compiles perfectly fine for me

Comment: Are you perhaps returning a string instead of a function in line ```return response```? The return type of ```Promise<Function>``` means that you must return a function. If ```response``` is a string, you are returning a string and must use ```Promise<string>``` as return type.

Comment: Yes, I intend returning a Function and not a String

Answer (score -1):

What you are actually declaring here is a method. Declaring methods with arrow syntax goes like this:

```
private methodName = (param: ParamType): TypeOfReturnable => {
    // remember to return something of type TypeOfReturnable
}
```

Comment: in my case, TypeOfReturnable returnable is of Promise<Function> so how do I add an async?

Comment: private methodName = async (param: ParamType): Promise<Function> => {
      // remember to return something of type TypeOfReturnable
    }

Comment: Sorry I deleted so many comments, I wans't quite understanding